# C# Create and Connect to a database that will work on every computer

Tags: c#, database

So i will go at a C# contest, and i need to work with databases.
I want to connect to one, and if they copy my whole project and move to an other PC, the program will work.

If i create a Database from Microsoft ACces, and put it into my project debug folder, I can make the connection string from the app path and will work on every PC.

But, i don't have Microsoft Acces or internet acces on thoose PCs, how can I create and connect to a database from Visual Studio, that will work on every PC ?

Comment: All you are saying is that you want to pass the connectiong string to app.config file?

Comment: Why not use EntityFramework Code first it creates a database for you if none exists?

Comment: C# (at least the .NET version) won't run on EVERY computer. Are you talking about PCs?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use ms-sql database.

You can use stand alone ms-sql database or database server for your project.
to access your stand alone ms-sql database in your put that mdf file in your project folder and use that db using connection string as "mydbfolder/dbname.mdf"

Comment: And I can connect with SqlConnection or OleDBConnection?

Comment: OleDBConnection is for oracle databases, here you need to use SqlConnection, same as you use for MS-SQL Servers.